# Express $x$ in terms of the other variables. 

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> [image: enter image desc>ription here]

Now, I got the first one by using the like triangles. This is my work, please tell me if I'm right: 
$$\frac{t}{h}=\frac{x+t}{r}\Rightarrow x+t=\frac{rt}{h}\Rightarrow x=\frac{rt}{h-t}$$
Now, I figure that $(b)$ must use the same concept (big triangle=little triangle). But I don't know what or how to do so. Please, give me general hints and only start me off, **do not** solve this problem for me.

Comment: Please check the last expression. It seems that there is a typo, and an error in calculating.

Comment: Let me re-work it.

Comment: When you subtract $t$ from both sides, you need a **common denominator**

Comment: So, multiply $x+t$ by $\frac{1}{h}$?

Comment: $x + t = \dfrac{rt}{h} \Rightarrow x = \dfrac{rt}{h} - t = \dfrac{rt}{h} - \dfrac{th}{h} = \cdots$

Comment: $x=\dfrac{t(r-h)}{h}$ or is it $x=t\left(\dfrac{r-h}{h}\right)$?

Comment: @AustinBroussard: Doesn't matter, both are right.

Comment: Austin, both are correct. Sorry... Fell asleep"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (b), use similarity to conclude that 
$$\frac{x}{t}=\frac{r}{w},$$
where $w$ is the remaining side of the little triangle. There remains some work to do.

Comment: Could I also conclude that: $$w^2=r^2-h^2\Rightarrow w=\sqrt{r^2-h^2}\Rightarrow t=\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$$ $$\dfrac{x}{r}=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{r^2-h^2}}$$ And then I'd solve that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @AustinBroussard: I had a typo, it is $\frac{x}{t}=\frac{r}{w}$. Your calculation of $w$ is correct, and your equation is correct. Now it is only a small step to the end.

Comment: Final answer coming to $x=\dfrac{rt}{\sqrt{r^2-h^2}}$?

Comment: @AustinBroussard: Yes, correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for the help. Your small comment actually helped a ton! How ironic.